# iOS - Autolayout not good for 3.5" screens

Tags: iphone, autolayout, iphone-4

I added Auto Layout to my app and it works perfectly for 4", 4.7" and 5.5" screens. However, when I tested it on the 3.5" (iPhone 4S), it was messy. A lot of objects were on top of each others. What can I do ? Is there a way to exclude iPhone 4S when uploading the app to iTunes Connect ? Will my app be rejected if it doesnt work for the iPhone 4S since it still supports iOS 9 ? (Using Xcode 7 GM)

EDIT :

I made another storyboard called "iPhone35" for the 3.5 inch and added this code to application function in AppDelegate.swift , but it always opens the Main.storyboard, which is for 4-inch and above screen sizes even if i choose iPhone 4S simulator.

```
let theBounds  = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let heightDevice = theBounds.size.height

    if heightDevice == 480 {
        let wantedStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPhone35", bundle: nil)
        let vc = wantedStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPage")
        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else {
        let wantedStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = wantedStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPage")
        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

what should i do ?

Comment: Your app needs to work with the iPhone 4S.  Additionally, if your app isn't universal, it will run on iPad using the iPhone 4S aspect ratio.

Comment: Then what should i do ? Can i create a different Main.storyboard just for the 4S ?

Comment: One approach is to create a different Storyboard file for the 4S.  Search SO for how to do that.  Another is to fix your constraints so that they work correctly on the shorter screen.  Without seeing your screens and your constraints, it is impossible for SO members to help you.

Comment: Thank you Vacawama. I was already in the process of doing it. Thank for you replies. Will get back to you when i'm done and added few lines of code to AppDelegate.swift

Comment: @vacawama , i made another storyboard called "iPhone35" , and i tried the code in my edit section but it didn't work , what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did was adding this function to AppDelegate.swift

```
func grabStoryBoard() -> UIStoryboard {

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().width

    if width == 480.0 {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPhone35", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard

}
```

and then adding these few lines inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.grabStoryBoard()
  self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController?
  self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And i also clicked the " is Initial View Controller " on the first controller of my new Storyboard.

The reason why width == 480.0 because my app is set to Landscape only.